# Limit and offset a search query that has a left join

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, limit, offset

I've got two tables: tasks and pages. The first page has a column that references the second table multiple times, called *page_number*. I want to get all fields of the first table and all *page number* values for the same *tasks.id*. My query for getting this data is as such:

```
SELECT
TASKS.ID,TASKS.URL,TASKS.ASSIGNEE,PAGES.TASK_ID,PAGES.PAGE_NUMBER
FROM TASKS
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM TASKS ORDER BY TASKS.ID LIMIT ? OFFSET ?)
AS T ON (TASKS.ID=T.ID)
LEFT JOIN PAGES ON (TASKS.ID=PAGES.TASK_ID);
```

This works, and I get an output like so:

```
      id  |          url          | assignee | task_id | page_number
------+-----------------------+----------+---------+-------------
   15 | /vector.pdf           |          |      15 |           1
   15 | /vector.pdf           |          |      15 |           2
   23 | /raster.pdf           |          |      23 |           1
   23 | /raster.pdf           |          |      23 |           2
   23 | /raster.pdf           |          |      23 |           4
 1001 | https://everette.com  |          |    1001 |           1
 1001 | https://everette.com  |          |    1001 |           2
 1002 | https://scarlett.com  |          |    1002 |           1
 1002 | https://scarlett.com  |          |    1002 |           2
 1002 | https://scarlett.com  |          |    1002 |           3
 1002 | https://scarlett.com  |          |    1002 |           4
 1002 | https://scarlett.com  |          |    1002 |           5
 1002 | https://scarlett.com  |          |    1002 |           6
 1002 | https://scarlett.com  |          |    1002 |           7
```

But I've come upon other requirements: I need to get a total count of the TASKS table as well in the same query (for pagination in the front-end), and I need to be able to search the resulting table (i.e look for any substring in the table) . 
To search the table, I did this:

```
SELECT 
TASKS.ID,TASKS.URL,TASKS.ASSIGNEE,PAGES.TASK_ID,PAGES.PAGE_NUMBER
FROM TASKS
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM TASKS ORDER BY TASKS.ID LIMIT ? OFFSET ?)
AS T ON (TASKS.ID=T.ID)
LEFT JOIN PAGES ON (TASKS.ID=PAGES.TASK_ID)
WHERE TASKS.URL  LIKE ?
OR CAST(TASKS.ID AS TEXT) LIKE ?
```

I do get results, but LIMIT and OFFSET work on the joined table before the WHERE clause, so I set LIMIT to something like 10 and OFFSET to 5, try to look for a record that's in the first 5 records and get no results because the matching records are further on in the original table:

```
SELECT
TASKS.ID,TASKS.URL,TASKS.ASSIGNEE,PAGES.TASK_ID,PAGES.PAGE_NUMBER
FROM TASKS
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM TASKS ORDER BY TASKS.ID LIMIT 10 OFFSET 5)
AS T ON (TASKS.ID=T.ID)
LEFT JOIN PAGES ON (TASKS.ID=PAGES.TASK_ID)
WHERE TASKS.URL  LIKE '%everette%'
OR CAST(TASKS.ID AS TEXT) LIKE 99
```

Actual output:

```
 id | url | assignee | task_id | page_number
----+-----+----------+---------+-------------
(0 rows)
```

Expected Output:

```
id  |          url          | assignee | task_id | page_number
------+-----------------------+----------+---------+-------------
1001 | https://everette.com  |          |    1001 |           1
1001 | https://everette.com  |          |    1001 |           2
```

How should I structure this query so I get all records that match the WHERE clause, getting at most *limit* tasks?

I'm using PostgreSQL, btw. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hi. This is not clear. What do "search the table" & "filtering with a WHERE clause at the end" mean exactly? Also it's not clear what you refer to by "resulting table" (some subselect? result of some FROM clause?) & "filtered results". Please read & act on [mcve]. Include code for parts you can do.

Comment: Sorry, I now added my complete SQL query and actual and desired output for clarity.

Comment: That is better. But a MCVE includes code we can cut & paste & run, including DDL & (small) input. Also: you are still not clear. What table is "the joined table before the WHERE clause" and what do you mean "LIMIT and OFFSET work on"? Please clearly identify specific subexpressions. Also your paragraph starting "I do get results, but" doesn't make sense. Eg what is "try to look for"? Again, talk about the values of clearly identified subexpressions. (And preferably demonstrate by giving code that works for parts.) And "search the resulting table" still doesn't mean anything. Etc.

Comment: PS You do not clearly describe what rows are supposed to appear in the output in terms of what rows appear in the input. PS If you want to limit to *matched* tasks, why do you LIMIT a table of *unmatched* tasks? PS If you want the DBMS to repeatedly return pages from a given subexpression value then you need to recalculate that value every time you ask for a new page.

Answer (score 1):

You could add that count to the column list:

```
SELECT ... column list ..., 
       (select count(*) from tasks) as total_task
FROM tasks
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY tasks.id LIMIT ? OFFSET ?) AS T 
    ON tasks.id = t.id
  LEFT JOIN pages ON tasks.id pages.task_id;
```